# Python - mesa : How to get instance variables of each object

Tags: python, instance-variables, mesa-abm

I am using mesa for my program. I am trying to execute my Model Class, but I got AttributeError from the Agent Class.

This is my script:

```
class ComtrModel (Model):
    """ A model with some number of Agents"""
    def __init__(self,N):
        self.num_agents = N
        self.schedule = RandomActivation(self)
        for i in range (N):
            a = CommuterAgent(i)
            self.schedule.add(a)

class CommuterAgent (Agent):
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.famsize = famsize
        self.distance = distance
        self.update_need = None


    def step(self):
        if  self.distance >= 10000:
            self.update_need = self.update_need()
            return

    def update_need (self, famsize):
        if self.famsize :
            self.famsize = famsize
            return
            prob_need()
```

How to get variables of each agent? I need to check it to make sure the model run properly.

So far this is my code to execute (on interactive session):

```
from src.ComtrModel import *
model = ComtrModel(5)
for i in range (10):
    model.step()

for key, value in CommuterAgent.step(model):
    print(key, value)
```

EDIT : But it returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:src/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from src.ComtrModel import *
  File "C:\src\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    for key, value in CommuterAgent.step(model):
  File "C:\src\ComtrModel.py", line 40, in step
    if  self.distance >= 10000:
AttributeError: 'ComtrModel' object has no attribute 'distance'
```

I also have tried something like this:

```
>>> hi_obj = hi()
>>> hi_obj.__dict__.keys()
```

But it only works for single object

Comment: *Where* does it raise that error? Show the full traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman EDIT for the full traceback

Comment: But this is exactly the same as your previous question. As was clearly answered there, you need to iterate through the `schedule` list.

Answer (score 0):

```
def __init__(self, model):
        self.famsize = famsize
        self.distance = distance
        self.update_need = None
```

Doesn't look correct. You don't pass famsize and distance as parameters.